# dynamic ingress to Kubernetes services with nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

i am trying to make a dynamic proxy_pass with nginx, doing something like that:

- Requests to foo.mywebsite.com are forwarded to service with foo name
- Requests to bar.mywebsite.com are forwarded to service with bar name

my nginx.conf works with static values, but with regex, works for about 5 minutes and then errors start

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-config-dns-file
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.*?)\.;
      resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local valid=5s;

      location /healthz {
        return 200;
      }

      location / {
        proxy_pass http://$subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local; 
      }
    }
```

my pod gets the service ip instead of the name, here are the logs

> 2019/11/11 22:30:40 [error] 6#6: *163 10.default.svc.cluster.local
>   could not be resolved (3: Host not found), client: 10.142.0.34,
>   server: ~^(?.*?)., request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host:
>   "10.142.0.34"

**10. is the beginning of ip to the point**.
I don't know what is going wrong, can anyone help me with this, thank you!!

Comment: Please share more information, for example your Nginx configuration. Also you are using baremetal or some cloud provider?

Comment: I fix the problem with a `proxy_set_header Host $host` inside location /, i use gce from Google Cloud, but thank you!!

Comment: Im glad to hear that, however, could you post your solution as an answer and explain? It might help someone in future with similar issue.

Comment: Oh sure, I will do this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIX WITH THIS**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-config-dns-file
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.*?)\.;
      resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local valid=5s;

      location /healthz {
        return 200;
      }

      location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host
        proxy_pass http://$subdomain.default.svc.cluster.local; 
      }
    }
```